# Ramdom Android cambiar números en el GUI

Tags: java, android

estoy creando un app que la cual me genera un numero aleatorio y este lo muestra en un textview, pero me gustaría que en la GUI del APK se evidencie como cambian los números dado que solo me muestra el ultimo numero.
(ejemplo: como si tubiera un contador y en un display se mostrara primero el 1 luego el 2, 3, 4...etc pero seria con números generados aleatoriamente.)

Codigo

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    TxwPrincipal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxwPrincipal);
    btnRamdom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRamdom);

   btnRamdom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           switch (v.getId()){
               case R.id.btnRamdom:
                  // correr();


                for (int i = 0; i <20; i++)
                   {
                       try {
                           Resources res = getResources();
                           Random rand = new Random();
                           int intvariablemaxvalue = rand.nextInt(res.getInteger(R.integer.intvariableRamdom));
                           TxwPrincipal.setText(String.valueOf(intvariablemaxvalue));

                       }
                       catch (Exception e)
                       {}
                   }
           }
       }
   });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el `for` se ejecuta demasiado rápido como para ver el cambio de número. Puedes hacer varios acercamientos para solucionarlo pero creo que para la práctica con un **CountDownTimer** debería bastarte.

En el onClickListener:

```
btnRamdom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
         case R.id.btnRamdom:

            //El onTick se repite cada 2000ms (2segundos) y dura 40000ms (40 segundos). 
            //Es decir que se va a repetir 20 veces cada 2 segundos.
            CountDownTimer waitTimer = new CountDownTimer(40000, 2000) {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //Se llama cada 2000ms = 2 segundos y cambias el numero
                 Resources res = getResources();
                 Random rand = new Random();
                 int intvariablemaxvalue = rand.nextInt(res.getInteger(R.integer.intvariableRamdom));
                 TxwPrincipal.setText(String.valueOf(intvariablemaxvalue));
             }

             public void onFinish() {
                //Si quieres hacer algo al final         
             }
            }.start();



         break;
        }
      }
 });
```

Si necesitas algo mas complejo / eficiente debes usar un Handler + Runnable + postDelayed(). Mas info de esto último aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434056/how-to-run-a-method-every-x-seconds

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó.